# How to sum up array values?

Tags: php, arrays

To make it clear, here's the inputted data:

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [SiteID] => 147
            [Amount] => 500.00
            [TransactionType] => D
        )

```
[1] => Array
    (
        [SiteID] => 145
        [Amount] => 500.00
        [TransactionType] => D
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [SiteID] => 145
        [Amount] => 500.00
        [TransactionType] => D
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [SiteID] => 147
        [Amount] => 500.00
        [TransactionType] => D
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [SiteID] => 146
        [Amount] => 500.00
        [TransactionType] => D
    )
[5] => Array
    (
        [SiteID] => 146
        [Amount] => 500.00
        [TransactionType] => D
    )
[6] => Array
    (
        [SiteID] => 145
        [Amount] => 500.00
        [TransactionType] => W
    )

[7] => Array
    (
        [SiteID] => 145
        [Amount] => 500.00
        [TransactionType] => W
    )

[8] => Array
    (
        [SiteID] => 146
        [Amount] => 330.00
        [TransactionType] => W
    )

[9] => Array
    (
        [SiteID] => 146
        [Amount] => 500.00
        [TransactionType] => W
    )

[10] => Array
    (
        [SiteID] => 3
        [Amount] => 500.00
        [TransactionType] => D
    )
```

I need to get the sum of all the transactions the same SiteID and it's TransactionType. Like for example:

D - Deposit, W - Redemption, R - Reload

Result: `array ([147]=>array([Deposit] => 1000, [Reload]=>3000, [Redemption]=>2000))`

Note: 147 is a SiteID.

I need to compute the Deposit, Reload, Redemption of all the transaction of same SiteID.

If SiteID exists more than once just add the Deposit, Reload and Redemption per cycle. :)

Please response. Thanks and guide me in proper way!!

Comment: So you want to sum up all the values from inside the big array?

Comment: [`$sum = array_sum($result['SiteId']);`](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php) ?

Comment: I've edit my question lately, so it will become more clear. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?php
$array=array ("SiteID"=>array("Deposit" => 1000, "Reload"=>3000, "Redemption"=>2000));
$val=0;
foreach($array["SiteID"] as $key=>$value){
$val=$val+$value;
}
echo $val;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$values = array(
    'Deposit' => 0,
    'Reload'       => 0,
    'Redemption' => 0
);
foreach ($array as $item) {
    $values[$item['SiteID']] += array_sum($item['SiteID']);
}
print_r($values);
```